# As a developer how do you deal with software version updates?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I know there are documentations. But the documentations seem to be for experienced developers because they contain minimalist information. Currently i only have book for gtk2, and gtk has upgraded to gtk3 and all the programs i run are giving compilation errors. Please give tips on not just gtk but all other software with respect to the general issue of upgradation.

Comment: That's a really broad and opinion-based question. One way is to not directly use the libraries throughout your application, but define wrappers for the components you want to use. This can be for sure problematic if you need to wrap a UI library. But minimizes the amount of code that is affected by breaking changes of a library update. In addition, libraries usually have a version strategy that has certain guarantees for certain version jumps. And major version updates will often have breaking changes.

Comment: The process is called porting or migration. Very often new library releases comes with porting guides to help with the transition. [Migrating from GTK+ 2.x to GTK+ 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html)

Comment: for gtk i would suggest you use gtk3 as gtk2 is very old and to make it work with latest version you would have to dynamically load the module and based on the version you would have to call the function..

Comment: If you need to learn  GTK3 then [Start Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeZXCNsTodx0EPcAfc6s0Ew)